# Firebase Storage, GB downloaded in realistic

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a 1.4GB video on Firebase Cloud Storage and currently it is a free tier.

Today I watched the video for 3-4times maybe (I clicked the storage video url link in console)

and then it showed me ("limited is over")

is that normal? I mean it is so expensive I guess.

I also have seen pricing documentation it saying "$0.12/GB"

then everytime people see the video, then I have to pay 0.12$?

I am so confusing right now

how could I be able to use this more cheaply?

Comment: It sounds like 3 times watching a 1.4GB video would get you well over the free tier of 1GB of downloads per day, so that'd be expected.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen if user wants to see the video, then it means the user has to download video?

Comment: Yes. The only way to see the data in a client is to download it to that client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, once you have reached and passed the free tier, you will start to be charged per GB. As clarified in the official pricing documentation - accessible [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing) - this falls under the network part of pricing which is explained as:

> Network usage charges apply when object data or object metadata is read from your Cloud Storage buckets.

So, due to the fact that everytime the file is open, it's read from your bucket, it will count towards your quotas/pricing. There isn't a specific cheapest way, as it varies from case to case - there are some cases for example, that using Datastore is cheaper than Cloud Storage. For this reason, I would recommend you to take a look at this very nice article [here](https://medium.com/@duhroach/google-cloud-storage-on-a-shoestring-budget-55f054fad436), where some examples and possible solutions to make your storage cheaper are provided, that I believe might help you.